# How to update data from remote server in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and now at the learning phase.

I am trying to update coins and diamond into the apache server from Unity game.

I got a URL from the backend developer

This is the URL

```
http://192.168.10.89:8080/GameManage/coindiamond/
```

POST request in the postman
[image]

When testing this url in  the postman. Coins and diamonds are updating fine.

But when I test in the Unity it won't. (Backend developer got no knowledge in unity).

Here is my C# code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PostJsonDataScript : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    string url = "http://192.168.10.89:8080/GameManage/coindiamond/";
    public int id, coin, diamond;

    private void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            id = 1;
            coin = 3;
            diamond = 4;
            UpdateUser(id, coin, diamond);
            Debug.Log("updated");
        }
    }


    public void UpdateUser(int id, int coin, int diamond)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("id", id);
        form.AddField("coin", coin);
        form.AddField("diamond", diamond);
    }
}
```

I am stuck here for 2 weeks already. Someone please help me

My code become like this

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class PostJsonDataScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int id, coin, diamond;
    string url = "http://192.168.10.89:8080/GameManage/coindiamond/";

    private IEnumerator UpdateUser(int userId, int userCoin, int userDiamond)
    {
        userId = 1;
        userCoin = 2;
        userDiamond = 3;

        var json = "{\"id\":\"" + userId + "\",\"coin\":\"" + userCoin + "\",\"diamond\":\"" + userDiamond + "\"}";

        Debug.Log(json);

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, json);

        {

            www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            www.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "text/json");



            yield return www.SendWebRequest();


            if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "Upload failed with: {0} - {1}", www.responseCode, www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            id = 1;
            coin = 2;
            diamond = 3;
            StartCoroutine(UpdateUser(id, coin, diamond));
        }
    }
}
```

Is my syntax correct?

I am getting Upload failed with : 400 - Generic/Unknown Http error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: In the code I give id = 1; coin = 2; diamond = 3;
When I run the program it should update these values into the server
But it won't @Johnny

Comment: If you're doing a post then the server needs to take care of the request. This is no longer Unity relevant but more likely php, nodeJS or other server side development.

Comment: You created a `WWWForm` but I don't see any attempt of creating a request e.g. using `UnityWebRequest.Post` in order to actually send the request to the server ...??

Comment: Btw `WWW` is also obsolete. Maybe better to use `UnityWebRequest.Post`...

Comment: @Johnny `WWW` is obsolete but not `WWWForm`. There is no usage of `WWW` in the question...

Comment: @derHugo It was but not anymore, the question has been updated... Actually it has been changed completely.

Comment: @Johnny oh sorry didn't see that ;)

Comment: @derHugo Sorry I change the code. These codes were coming from a youtube video. He doesn't need to use UnityWebRequest.Post to update the data from the local server.
Here is the link to the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4zh4xl4vLc&t=939s
 Thank you for caring and answering :D

Comment: @Johnny Sorry I change the code. These codes were coming from a youtube video. He doesn't need to use UnityWebRequest.Post to update the data from the local server.
Here is the link to the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4zh4xl4vLc&t=939s
 Thank you for caring and answering :D

Comment: @KhantMinSiThu if so then you are missing the very last line where it actually post the data through `WWW`... Regardless it is obsolete.

Comment: This tut is from 2017 and for Unity Versión 5.6. as we said now you should use `UnityWebRequest` as `WWW` was marked obsolete quite a while ago already. Using `WWW` might probably still work though but you should try `UnityWebRequest` and see what errors you get..

Answer (score 2):

You created your form but you never actually send it to the server!

Use a [UnityWebRequest.Post](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html)

```
private IEnumerator UpdateUser(int userId, int userCoin, int userDiamond)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("id", userId);
    form.AddField("coin", userCoin);
    form.AddField("diamond", userDiamond);

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "Upload failed with: {0} - {1}", www.responseCode, www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!", this);
        }
    }
}
```

And start it instead like

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        id = 1;
        coin = 3;
        diamond = 4;
        StartCoroutine (UpdateUser(id, coin, diamond));
    }
}
```

---

Note that also the usage of `WWWForm` is the legacy way and is only still supported in order to allow migrating from `WWW` which is obsolete.

You might want to use a [MultipartFormDataSection](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormDataSection.html) instead as shown [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-SendingForm.html)

---

However it seems that in `postman` you are actually posting a JSON string rather than a form data and also using strings as values instead of numeric ones. So maybe you should try to do this instead

```
var json = "{\"id\":\"" + userId + "\",\"coin\":\"" + userCoin + "\",\"diamond\":\"" + userDiamond + "\"}";

UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, json)
{
    ...
}
```

---

Sidenote: `192.168.10.89:8080` is a local network address and is not routed in the internet. So it only works if the device you run Unity in is within the same local network as your server or at least routed correctly.

Comment: I copied your code and tested many times.
Still not updating.

Now my brain is on fire.
Any way thank you for your responses.

Do you think Server side codes need to be changed?
@derHugo

Comment: @KhantMinSiThu I don't know your server side code ... do you get any error from the request or do you get the ouput `Form upload complete!`? If the Unity side works than yes something is probably wrong with the server or the form itself .. note that what you send in `postman` seems to be a JSON string rather than a form ...

Comment: Yeah its is a Json string . I try changing according to your teachings.
but the data won't go into the server.

I got an error message { Generic/Unknown Http error }

Also I am not getting any debug.log both upload failed or form upload complete.

Comment: If oyou don't get any debug log than where do you get the `error message { Generic/Unknown Http error }`?

Comment: Sorry It's coming from upload failure.
Now  I try to add 
THESE 2 LINES

 www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   www.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "text/json");

Because I got an error code 405.

But after that I am getting error code 400 + Generic/unknown Http error still won't upload @derHugo